# Validation using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a validation like, String should contain at least **one alphabet**, or **number**. It may contain _ or - as optional character in between. The string should start and end with an **alphabet** or a **number**. I tried using many **Regex**, but I can't achieve this. Here is my RegEx code :

```
public static boolean isValidURL(String inputString) {
    try {
        boolean isValid = true;
        Pattern letter = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z0-9]");
        String restPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\s]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
        Matcher hasLetter = letter.matcher(inputString);
        if (hasLetter.find()) {
            if (inputString.matches(restPattern)) {
                isValid = true;
            } else {
                isValid = false;
            }
        } else {
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**And My Unit Test** :

```
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("res"));
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("res_rer"));
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("res-rer"));
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("res232A"));
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("232DFA"));
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("23_323"));
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("23"));
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("A2s"));
    assertEquals(false, Validator.isValidURL("_"));
    assertEquals(false, Validator.isValidURL("-"));
    assertEquals(false, Validator.isValidURL("@"));
    assertEquals(false, Validator.isValidURL("@GR$"));
    assertEquals(false, Validator.isValidURL("_GR_"));
    assertEquals(false, Validator.isValidURL("GR_"));
    assertEquals(false, Validator.isValidURL("GR_"));
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("s"));
    assertEquals(true, Validator.isValidURL("4"));
```

Last two assert getting failed. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: did you want to allow spaces?

Comment: The regex ends with a + quantifier so an extra character is needed at the end and since the last two strings are of length one it fails.

Comment: If I put optional quantifier ?
^[a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\s]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
The second assert itself getting failed.

Comment: Can there be multiple consecutive `-` and `_`?

Comment: Ya multiple consecutive

Comment: Sorry, no multiple consecutive. It may contains _ and - as optional char in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below regex would allow one or more alphanumeric characters and also allows `-` or `_` in-between the alphanumeric chars but not at the first or at the last.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gG9vW6/8)

If you don't want consecutive `_` or `-` then remove the `+` following the character class which was present inside the non-capturing group.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: This is going to run into backtracking hell. Remove the optional quantifier `?`

Comment: assertEquals(true, UtilityFunction.isValidURL("23___323"));
This assert getting failed.

Comment: `It may contains _ and - as optional char in between`

Comment: just add a plus `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$` see http://regex101.com/r/gG9vW6/8

Answer (score 2):

This should restrict the input to start and end with alphanumeric, and allow multiple consecutive `-` and `_` within the input.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]++(?:[-_]++[a-zA-Z0-9]++)*+$
```

I turn all the quantifiers possessive (`++` and `*+` instead of `+` and `*`), to disallow backtracking.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I develop the solution independently, but slower in answering the question, since I need to get all the assumptions by the OP straight.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\s]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9])$
```

Just add one more or condition which accepting either alphabet or number

Comment: Correctness aside, this will do useless backtracking, since `[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\s]?` is optional, and you have `[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+` in a row.